# Creating a Russian roulette game in R

Tags: r

I wonder if anyone could help me to create a russian roulette game in R? I'm a total novice at R and at writing code in general. I would be very grateful for your help!

The game is played with a revolver equipped with a rotatable magazine of six shots. The revolver is loaded with one shot. The first duellist, A, rotates the magazine at random, points the revolver at his head and presses the trigger. If, afterwards, he is still alive, he hands the revolver to the other duellist, B, who acts in the same way as A. The players shoot alternately in this manner,
until a shot goes off.

All I (with help) have come up with so far is:

```
shot<-runif(1,min=0,max=1)
killed<-runif(1,min=0,max=1/6)
roulette<-function()
{

    while  (shot!=killed) 
    { 
        shot <- runif(1,min=0,max=1)
        print("click")
        if (shot<killed)
            break
    } 
    {
        print ("Dead")
    }
}
for (i in 1:5)
{
    roulette()
}
```

How do I count the number of times A or B has been killed in e g 1000 games? Some variable which can switch between A and B and then store the results in a list?

Comment: The roulette function is not keeping track of who wins or loses. You could make the function return a "win" or a "lose" (depending on whether "Dead" happens after an even or an odd number of tries), then run the function 1000 times. The number of times A wins is the same as the number of times B loses, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the while statement and count the number of iterations.

Odd number of shots fired = A dies, even number of shots fired = B dies

```
n <- 1000
outcomes <- cbind(rep("click",n),rep("click",n),numeric(length=n),numeric(length=n))
colnames(outcomes) <- c("finalA","finalB","nClickA","nClickB")

for (i in 1:nrow(outcomes)){

  shot<-runif(1,min=0,max=1) #first shot
  count <- 1

  while (shot > 1/6) { #chance of dying is 1/6, so every 0 < shot < 1/6
                       #will be considered "death"
    shot <- runif(1,min=0,max=1) #if not dead, shoot again
    count <- count + 1 #and count the iterations
    }

  #replace "click" by "dead" for either A or B
  ifelse ((count %% 2) > 0, #if count is odd number = A killed, else: B killed
      (outcomes[i,1] <- "dead"), #replace the "click"s in outcomes matrix
      (outcomes[i,2] <- "dead"))

  #count and insert the number of clicks for each player
  #if count = odd number, both had (count/2)-1 clicks
  nclick <- count- 1 #the number of clicks is always the number of triggerpulls minus 1

  if ((nclick %% 2) == 0) {outcomes[i,3:4] <- nclick/2
  #if nclick is even number, both A and B took (nclick/2) clicks

  } else {
          outcomes[i,3] <- nclick/2+0.5
          outcomes[i,4] <- nclick/2-0.5}
  #if nclick is odd number, A took one click more than B
}

outcomes <- as.data.frame(outcomes)
table(outcomes$finalA)
table(outcomes$finalB)
```

---

**Edit: If the probability of dying is not the same for each A and B**, you could include an if-statement with different death probabilities inside the while loop, which will terminate once either A or B dies (`death=TRUE`).

```
  shot <- runif(1,min=0,max=1) #first shot
  count <- 1
  death <- logical(length=1) #new object needed to terminate the while-loop
  if (shot < 0.6) {death <- TRUE} #A is already dead with p=.60

  while (death != TRUE) { #if A survived the first trigger-pull, start while-loop

    if (count %% 2 == 1) { #if count is odd, it's B's turn
      shot <- runif(1,min=0,max=1) #next trigger-pull
      if (shot < 0.8) {death <- TRUE} #B's probability of dying is .80
      count <- count + 1

    } else { #if count is even, it's A's turn again
      shot <- runif(1,min=0,max=1)
      if (shot < 0.6) {death <- TRUE}
      count <- count +1
    } #and this loop goes on until death = TRUE

  }
```

---

**Edit: What if the bullets are in adjacent chambers?**
If the bullets are in adjacent chambers, there are six possibile positions, two covering each chamber. First trigger-pull has p(death)=2/6. If no shot was fired, we know neither of the two bullet positions was true, to next triggerpull has p(death)=1/4, and so on.

```
count <- 1
k <- 5
death <- sample(c(T,T,F,F,F,F)[1:k],1)
while (death != TRUE){k <- k-1  
                      death <- sample(c(T,F,F,F)[1:k],1)
                      count <- count +1}
```

Comment: @Anna Did this solve your issue? Please consider confirming (by green check mark) any answer that was helpful with your problem.

Comment: Thanks very much for your and @cumin's answer! I wonder if you could explain the command " %%2" a little bit more? I know that %% is a arithmetic operator, but I don't quite understand the explanation in R tutorial:  "Give the remainder of the first vector with the second". Thanks in advance!

Comment: One more question: it seems to me that the games in your answer consists of just 2 trials? Or do I misunderstand? But each game can have any possible number of clicks before death.

Comment: If each row is a result of one game (one win, one dies), would it be possible in some way to get the number of trials for each of A and B before they die? That is for example in one game: 4 clicks (A), 4 clicks (B) and one shot (A). Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `count %% 2` will divide count by two and output the "rest". So if `count` is 7, then 7:2 = "3 with rest 1", the output will be 1. `count` is also the key to the other two questions: it equals the number of "trigger-pulls" in each game. So `count = 7` means that A had three clicks, B had three clicks, and eventually A had a bullet. I edited the code, now there is another counter for the number of clicks, `nclicks`, which is added to the `outcomes` matrix.

Comment: Try adding `print(shot)` to the while-statement and then run it individually a few times, including the two lines of code that precede the while statement. It should help you see what is going on there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has been so helpful! Now I understand count %%2 and all the steps :) Do you have some tip how I shall think if I A has probability say 0.6 to be killed and B say 0.8? I have tried different approaches but nothing seems to work. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @Anna I added a section below that will do this, see if it serves your purpose. Btw I just noticed that the outcomes data frame will say "click" for B even when A died at the first trigger-pull, which means B did not actually have a click. You would need to correct that in your results.

Comment: I have tried to edit the game so that I have one pistol with two bullets, without spinning the barrel. I have used the sample-function  but I don't get it to work. Inside the while-loop the same number appear even if I use sample without replacement. How can I get different number to appear? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I understand that the game would still end at the moment the first person dies? Perhaps sample() with true/false statements could help? My idea would be to sample from a vector c(T,T,F,F,F,F), and at every round, the vector is shortened by one element at the end, until a T is sampled. # = line break `count <- 1 #
k <- 6 #
death <- sample(c(T,T,F,F,F,F)[1:k],1) #
while (death != TRUE){k <- k-1 #
                    death <- sample(c(T,T,F,F,F,F)[1:k],1) #
                    count <- count +1}`

Comment: This loop starts with a death probability of 2/6 and increases probability by 1/6 at each round. The latest it ends is at count=5.

Comment: Btw +1 for using sample() instead of runif() for the case where both players have equal death probability. Much better!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm sorry I didn't mention that the game this time only consists of two trials. The true/false work if the two bullets are in any chambers, but if they are in two adjacent chambers I think I must use the sample with numbers or am I wrong? Because if the shots are in chamber 5 and 6, then the chamber 4 will give a bullet next time the revolver are fired, but if chamber 1,2 or 3 are choosen the first time, the probability to get shot the second time is zero.

Comment: But you do not know in which chambers the bullets are beforehand, so every triggerpull is still a random draw. With the two bullets in adjacent chambers, there are 6 different possible positions, and every chamber is covered by two of them. That makes the probability of the very first shot to have a bullet in chamber 1 p=2/6. If no shot, neither of the two positions was true, so for second chamber: p=1/4. Third chamber: p=1/3 and so on.

Comment: You could use the code in my comment above, with `death <- sample(c(T,T,F,F,F,F),1)` (hence, p=2/6) outside the while loop, and `sample(c(T,F,F,F)[1:k],1)` inside the loop (p=1/4 at first, then increasing to 1/3 etc.).

Comment: Many thanks! I had one more question, when I try to calculate the average number of shots it takes for a duellist to be killed a get a number far too high, about 17 shots for a game for 10 000 games. The expected value is much lower. How could that be? The games (I have used print(shot) in 10 games) seem give correct number of clicks. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hm, that is hard to tell without the corresponding code. Perhaps you can have somebody look at this directly?

Answer (score 1):

I understand the model to be "keep trading the gun back and forth until numshots number of shots are fired". I modeled the loaded chamber like the roll of a die, setting "6" to be the fatal roll

```
roulette <- function(numshots=1000){
  killed = 6 # fatal face on a die
  killshots = 0
  won = 0
  i = 0
  while (killshots < numshots){
     shot = sample(1:6, size=1, replace=T) # rolling a die
     i = i + 1  # keep track of even or odd # of tries
     if ( (shot == killed) ){
      killshots = killshots + 1
      if (i%%2 == 1){
        won = won + 1
      }
    }
  }
  return(data.frame(A = won, B = numshots-won))
}

> roulette()
    A  B
1 502 498
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at [another post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QGny.png) earlier this morning about a more complex Russian Roulette game in R, and decided to make a function for a simple version. In your example, you have "shuffling" because the chamber is spun before each turn.

```
RR <- function(PLAYERS, S = 6){
    D <- 0
    i <- 0

    while(D != 1){
        P <- sample(c(1, rep(0, times = S-1)))[1]
        i <- i + 1
        if(P == 1){
            D <- 1
            }
    }

    L <- rep(PLAYERS, length.out = i)[i]
    L

    }
```

In this function the `while` argument is utilized to play rounds until someone wins; `S` is the amount of chambers in the gun, and is set to 6 as default to make this a 6-shooter, `D` is coding whether a player has died (1) or not (0), `i` is the round of the game, `P` is the random position of the bullet in the chamber, and if P = 1 (the bullet is in the first chamber after spinning), the player dies and the game is over. The loser (`L`) is assigned and printed.

It appears that Clint Eastwood and John Wayne fancy a game...

```
> PLAYERS <- c("Eastwood", "Wayne")
> RR(PLAYERS)
[1] "Wayne"
```

But what happens over 10000 games?

```
> n <- 10000
> RRres <- rep(NA, times = n)
> 
> for(i in 1:n){
+ RRres[i] <- RR(PLAYERS)
+ }
> 
> table(RRres)
RRres
Eastwood    Wayne 
    5393     4607
```

It looks like Clint shouldn't feel so lucky himself... but that's because he is always going first: **there is an advantage in going last when you shuffle the chamber**, because if the player(s) before you die, you don't play - it's more likely that a game will be over in few rounds than in many (Probability that a given round [n] results in the killshot = (1/6) * ((5/6)^n), where 1/6 is the risk of shuffling on to the loaded chamber, and (5/6)^n is the probability that someone already lost).

[image]

Therefore, you might want to **randomize the order of players** in each game using the `sample` function:

```
> for(i in 1:n){
+ RRres[i] <- RR(sample(PLAYERS))
+ }
> 
> table(RRres)
RRres
Eastwood    Wayne 
    5017     4983
```

Note that this function **works for any amount of players** (e.g. 26 players):

```
> for(i in 1:n){
+ RRres[i] <- RR(sample(LETTERS[1:26]))
+ }
> 
> table(RRres)
RRres
  A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z 
396 362 378 368 373 388 383 398 390 372 379 382 395 393 377 389 381 386 375 379 375 382 379 430 393 397
```